move rows in df by the value of the cells with pandas
I have the following input table and i want to obtain the output table.
To do this I have to check the last part of the content of each individual cell from row 14 to the end of the file and, if i have a match, move the entire cell value in the rows 10, 11, 12, 13 ("STA ATT", "TEC", "D C P", "A SPV")
I have to do this until the last column
I wrote a code to do so that works, but it is very confusing, inefficient and slow. I wrote it with openpyxl but i think is the slowest way to do it and i think pandas offer a fastest way to do it.
In the example below:
for the column 095 i have to move the content in row 16 to cell 10 and the content in row 17 to cell 11
for the first column 088 i have to move the content in row 14 to cell 12, 15 to cell 13, 17 to cell 11
for the SECOND column 088 i have to move the content in row 18 to cell 12, 19 to cell 10, 16 to cell 10, 20 to cell 11
and so on..
From ROW 14 there are only 4 values in every column that needs to be moved in the corresponding ROW
The values are not necessarily consecutive but from the first value (that can be an empty cell) the remaining values ​​are in the next 3 cells.
For example in column 095 i'll move only 2 values, X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.STA ATT and X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.TEC because the first two cells are empty
Can you help me improving the performance?
with the code I wrote it takes me 15 minutes to complete the task with df of 482 col and 8k rows
#Input
0  | Unnamed: 0                 | 095                               | 088                             | 088                               | 713                             | 714                           |
1  | APP SPV                    |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
2  | DAT                        |                                   | 11/04/2024                      | 11/04/2024                        |                                 |                               |
3  | ST AT                      | AN                                | ABA                             | ABA                               |                                 | PP                            |
4  | TEC                        | TOP                               |                                 |                                   | CAS                             |                               |
5  | DATE                       |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
6  |                            |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
7  |                            |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
8  |                            |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
9  |                            |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
10 | STA ATT                    |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
11 | TEC                        |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
12 | A SPV                      |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
13 | D C P                      |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
14 | A SPV_05.04.2024 16:40     |                                   | X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.A SPV   |                                   |                                 |                               |
15 | D C P_05.04.2024 16:40     |                                   | X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.D C P   |                                   |                                 |                               |
16 | STA ATT_05.04.2024 16:40   | X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.STA ATT   |                                 |                                   | X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.STA ATT |                               |
17 | TEC_05.04.2024 16:40       | X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.TEC       | X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.TEC     |                                   |                                 |                               |
18 | A SPV_05.04.2024 18:37     |                                   |                                 |  X XX X_05.04.2024 18:37.A SPV    |                                 |                               |
19 | STA ATT_05.04.2024 18:37   |                                   |                                 |  X XX X_05.04.2024 18:37.STA ATT  |                                 |                               |
20 | TEC_05.04.2024 18:37       |                                   |                                 |  X XX X_05.04.2024 18:37.TEC      |                                 |                               |
21 | A SPV_06.04.2024 10:11     |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 | X XX X_06.04.2024 10:11.A SPV |

#Output
0  | Unnamed: 0                 | 095                               | 088                             | 088                               | 713                             | 714                           |
1  | APP SPV                    |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
2  | DAT                        |                                   | 11/04/2024                      | 11/04/2024                        |                                 |                               |
3  | ST AT                      | AN                                | ABA                             | ABA                               |                                 | PP                            |
4  | TEC                        | TOP                               |                                 |                                   | CAS                             |                               |
5  | DATE                       |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
6  |                            |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
7  |                            |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
8  |                            |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
9  |                            |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
10 | STA ATT                    | X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.STA ATT   |                                 | X XX X_05.04.2024 18:37.STA ATT   | X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.STA ATT |                               |
11 | TEC                        | X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.TEC       | X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.TEC     | X XX X_05.04.2024 18:37.TEC       |                                 |                               |
12 | A SPV                      |                                   | X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.A SPV   | X XX X_05.04.2024 18:37.A SPV     |                                 |X XX X_06.04.2024 10:11.A SPV  |
13 | D C P                      |                                   | X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.D C P   |                                   |                                 |                               |
14 | A SPV_05.04.2024 16:40     |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
15 | D C P_05.04.2024 16:40     |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
16 | STA ATT_05.04.2024 16:40   |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
17 | TEC_05.04.2024 16:40       |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
18 | A SPV_05.04.2024 18:37     |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
19 | STA ATT_05.04.2024 18:37   |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
20 | TEC_05.04.2024 18:37       |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |
21 | A SPV_06.04.2024 10:11     |                                   |                                 |                                   |                                 |                               |



#Code
def find_between_r( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.rindex( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.rindex( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""


cont = 0
val_a = ""
val_b = ""
val_c = ""
val_d = ""
val_cel_2 = ""
for colum in range(2,wsa.max_column+1):
    cont = 0
    Ul_pa_0 = ""
    val_cel_2 = ""
    for ro in range(15,wsa.max_row+1):
        val_cel_2 = ""
        In_St_At= 0
        In_Te= 0
        In_App_SPV = 0
        In_Da_Ci_Pr = 0
        val_cel_2 = str(wsa.cell(ro,colum).value)
        if val_cel_2 != None:
            if "_" in val_cel_2:
                Ul_pa_0 = find_between_r(val_cel_2, "_",".")
                wsa.cell(6,colum).value = Ul_pa_0
                if cont < 1:
                    cont = cont +1
                    ro = ro
                    ro1= ro +1
                    ro2 = ro +2
                    ro3 = ro +3
                    
                    Val = wsa.cell(ro,colum).value
                    Val1 = wsa.cell(ro1,colum).value
                    Val2 = wsa.cell(ro2,colum).value
                    Val3 = wsa.cell(ro3,colum).value

                    if Val == None or Val == '':
                        Val = "Null"
                        val_a  = "Null"
                    if Val1 == None or Val1 == '':
                        Val1 = "Null"
                        val_b  = "Null"
                    if Val2 == None or Val2 == '':
                        Val2 = "Null"
                        val_c  = "Null"
                    if Val3 == None or Val3 == '':
                        Val3 = "Null"
                        val_d  = "Null"

                    if Val != None and Val != "Null":
                        val_a = Val.split("_")[1]
                        Val = Val.split("_")[0]
                    if Val1 != None and Val1 != "Null":
                        val_b = Val1.split("_")[1]
                        Val1 = Val1.split("_")[0]
                    if Val2 != None and Val2 != "Null":
                        val_c = Val2.split("_")[1]
                        Val2 = Val2.split("_")[0]
                    if Val3 != None and Val3 != "Null":
                        val_d = Val3.split("_")[1]
                        Val3 = Val3.split("_")[0]

                    if "STA ATT" in val_a and Val != "Null" and In_St_At!= 1:
                        wsa.cell(11,colum).value = Val
                        In_St_At= 1
                    if "STA ATT" in val_b and Val1 != "Null" and In_St_At!= 1:
                        wsa.cell(11,colum).value = Val1
                        In_St_At= 1
                    if "STA ATT" in val_c and Val2 != "Null" and In_St_At!= 1:
                        wsa.cell(11,colum).value = Val2
                        In_St_At= 1
                    if "STA ATT" in val_d and Val3 != "Null" and In_St_At!= 1:
                        wsa.cell(11,colum).value = Val3
                        In_St_At= 1
                    if "TEC" in val_a and Val != "Null" and In_Te!= 1:
                        wsa.cell(12,colum).value = Val
                        In_Te= 1
                    if "TEC" in val_b and Val1 != "Null" and In_Te!= 1:
                        wsa.cell(12,colum).value = Val1
                        In_Te= 1
                    if "TEC" in val_c and Val2 != "Null" and In_Te!= 1:
                        wsa.cell(12,colum).value = Val2
                        In_Te= 1
                    if "TEC" in val_d and Val3 != "Null" and In_Te!= 1:
                        wsa.cell(12,colum).value = Val3
                        In_Te= 1
                    if "A SPV" in val_a and Val != "Null" and In_App_SPV != 1:
                        wsa.cell(13,colum).value = Val
                        In_App_SPV = 1
                    if "A SPV" in val_b and Val1 != "Null" and In_App_SPV != 1:
                        wsa.cell(13,colum).value = Val1
                        In_App_SPV = 1
                    if "A SPV" in val_c and Val2 != "Null" and In_App_SPV != 1:
                        wsa.cell(13,colum).value = Val2
                        In_App_SPV = 1
                    if "A SPV" in val_d and Val3 != "Null" and In_App_SPV != 1:
                        wsa.cell(13,colum).value = Val3
                        In_App_SPV = 1
                    if "D C P" in val_a and Val != "Null" and In_Da_Ci_Pr != 1:
                        wsa.cell(14,colum).value = Val
                        In_Da_Ci_Pr = 1
                    if "D C P" in val_b and Val1 != "Null" and In_Da_Ci_Pr != 1:
                        wsa.cell(14,colum).value = Val1
                        In_Da_Ci_Pr = 1
                    if "D C P" in val_c and Val2 != "Null" and In_Da_Ci_Pr != 1:
                        wsa.cell(14,colum).value = Val2
                        In_Da_Ci_Pr = 1
                    if "D C P" in val_d and Val3 != "Null" and In_Da_Ci_Pr != 1:
                        wsa.cell(14,colum).value = Val3
                        In_Da_Ci_Pr = 1

improve of performance with pandas or a faster method
EDIT ----------------------------------------------
Method made by @mozway is a big step forward but some values are missing in the resulting output. I made some corrections and now it is working. thx @mozway i offer you a coffe

Use a database.

i can't .......

IIUC, you can use a merge for each column after extracting the suffix of each Series:
out = df.copy()

ref = df.iloc[10:, 1].reset_index(name='ref')

out.iloc[10:, 2:] = (
    df.iloc[14:, 2:]
      .apply(lambda s: ref
             .merge(s.rename('out'), how='left', left_on='ref',
                    right_on=s.str.extract(r'([^.]+)$', expand=False))
             .set_index('index')['out'])
)

Note that, like in your description, the positions of the windows to use are hardcoded (after column 2, after row 10, after row 14).
Output:
     0                         1                                2                              3                                4                                5                              6
0    0                Unnamed: 0                              095                            088                              088                              713                            714
1    1                   APP SPV                              NaN                            NaN                              NaN                              NaN                            NaN
2    2                       DAT                              NaN                     11/04/2024                       11/04/2024                              NaN                            NaN
3    3                     ST AT                               AN                            ABA                              ABA                              NaN                             PP
4    4                       TEC                              TOP                            NaN                              NaN                              CAS                            NaN
5    5                      DATE                              NaN                            NaN                              NaN                              NaN                            NaN
6    6                       NaN                              NaN                            NaN                              NaN                              NaN                            NaN
7    7                       NaN                              NaN                            NaN                              NaN                              NaN                            NaN
8    8                       NaN                              NaN                            NaN                              NaN                              NaN                            NaN
9    9                       NaN                              NaN                            NaN                              NaN                              NaN                            NaN
10  10                   STA ATT  X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.STA ATT                            NaN  X XX X_05.04.2024 18:37.STA ATT  X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.STA ATT                            NaN
11  11                       TEC      X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.TEC    X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.TEC      X XX X_05.04.2024 18:37.TEC                              NaN                            NaN
12  12                     A SPV                              NaN  X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.A SPV    X XX X_05.04.2024 18:37.A SPV                              NaN  X XX X_06.04.2024 10:11.A SPV
13  13                     D C P                              NaN  X XX X_05.04.2024 16:40.D C P                              NaN                              NaN                            NaN
14  14    A SPV_05.04.2024 16:40                              NaN                            NaN                              NaN                              NaN                            NaN
15  15    D C P_05.04.2024 16:40                              NaN                            NaN                              NaN                              NaN                            NaN
16  16  STA ATT_05.04.2024 16:40                              NaN                            NaN                              NaN                              NaN                            NaN
17  17      TEC_05.04.2024 16:40                              NaN                            NaN                              NaN                              NaN                            NaN
18  18    A SPV_05.04.2024 18:37                              NaN                            NaN                              NaN                              NaN                            NaN
19  19  STA ATT_05.04.2024 18:37                              NaN                            NaN                              NaN                              NaN                            NaN
20  20      TEC_05.04.2024 18:37                              NaN                            NaN                              NaN                              NaN                            NaN
21  21    A SPV_06.04.2024 10:11                              NaN                            NaN                              NaN                              NaN                            NaN

If you have many columns, if might be more memory efficient to loop manually over them.
Here is the updated code that matches your real-life file (the row/cols indices are slightly different you have to be careful to update them). You also had duplicates, so the code below only keeps the first match and discards the other(s) (you could also aggregate them if preferred).
out = df.copy()

ref = df.iloc[9:13, 0].reset_index(name='ref')
target_idx = df.index[10:]

for col_idx in range(1, df.shape[1]):
    s = df.iloc[14:, col_idx].dropna()
    key = s.str.extract(r'([^.]+)$', expand=False)
    m = ~key.duplicated()
    out.iloc[10:, col_idx] = (
        ref.merge(s[m].rename('out'), how='left', left_on='ref',
                  right_on=key[m])
           .set_index('index')['out'].reindex(target_idx)
    )


I got this error:
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.46 MiB for an array with shape (2, 227052) and data type object

Are you using a low memory system? Please provide a [mre] of your input by editing your question with the output of df.to_dict('tight'). I provided an alternative approach that should be more memory efficient.

my sistem is 8,00 GB RAM AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 5675U

with new method i got this error ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence at out.iloc[10:, col_idx] = (

@DavideC. can you have multiple matches per column? If yes, how should they be handled? As requested above, can you provide a [mre] that triggers this error? It's much harder to try to debug without a reproducible example.

i can provide it to you by mail

Cant' your craft a MRE of 20 rows or so that reproduces the error? If really the full dataset is needed, then you have to host it somewhere to share it.

hi mozway, here it is https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f3b2dfd198c542d07fc1e6cef196eb9f20240412115019/c33e787a30a695248960b2963ea4c98d20240412115030/0fd55a

@DavideC. I'm confused, your file doesn't have the same organization, the rows with STA ATT/TEC/A SPV/D C P are not present in the first column at indices 10:14.

you can find the updated file here https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1f3e74c653c9da34ca358277566ce6ea20240412122020/c0b895969e0a89fce7b2cb114668ebf520240412122028/0adb8b

@DavideC. I see, there were several cases that were not in your example and the indices were different. The updated code works with this particular file but you have to carefully study and understand the code to be able to adapt it to potential other files. Given your peculiar format it's difficult to write truly generic code.

your method is working but some values are missing as you can see in this image https://imgur.com/a/DapyWVZ . Looks like STA ATT and A SPV are not moved correctly

@DavideC. I don't really know what this image represents. Please keep in mind that the objective of stackoverflow is not to write a customized code for your specific problem. It's to provide answers to question that can be useful to everyone. You have a very specific setup here and I believe my answer already gives you a solid strategy to handle your issue. Now, it's impossible to make a fully generic code without a clear set of specifications, and not in the scope of stackoverflow anyway. Please read again [ask] and pandas example to see what is expected here.

To give you an example of a question with a clear requirement and a well crafted MRE, you can read this recent one.

I'm just saying that the code doesn't work because some values are missing. in the attached file "expected result.xlsx" indicates the desired and "result.xlsx" indicates the result of the code you kindly provided.  i reduced the file size to make it more understandable. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/28685e1434e40267385e0db4ba04ecd820240412134638/6ea0aa962724c6af7e2732275f9ffc8620240412134646/bd9d94
1 elemento

this image (https://imgur.com/a/HOU5HoA) is also showing, marked red, values that are missing running your code (size of the data is reduced to make it mode clear)
